# How can I export my RSS feeds from My Yahoo?

Tags: rss, yahoo

I'd like to switch readers, but I've got too many feeds to do setup a new reader manually.

Is there a way to export my RSS feeds from My Yahoo to another reader?

Comment: You can't, it's a black hole

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've found out.  Yahoo really sucks.

Answer (score 1):

Point your browser to this URL:

http://api2.my.yahoo.com/2.0/content/getsubs

That'll give you an OPML version of your RSS subscriptions.

Comment: The xml file I get only contains a deprecated API error:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<yc:status xmlns:yc="urn:yahoo:content:v3.0" return="0" code="ERROR_API_DEPRECATED">
  <yc:text>Deprecated API.</yc:text>
</yc:status>

Comment: Hmm. Serves me right for not testing it out. Can you find an option there to download OPML files? (An OPML file is the format used to move RSS subscription lists from one RSS reader to another).

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: [Use this tool](http://gen-opml.ekingery.com/)

I wrote into Yahoo support about this on 04/14/11 and they replied with a long version of 'No' (see below for details). First I threw together a quick shell script to convert the HTML source of a My Yahoo page into an OPML file which can be imported into Google Reader or most other reasonable RSS readers. As an excuse to learn some Ruby, I also [coded](https://github.com/ekingery/My-Yahoo-Source-to-OPML-Generator) a [web based opml generator](http://gen-opml.ekingery.com/).

--

```
./my_yahoo_source_to_opml.sh ~/tmp/my_yahoo_feed_source.html ~/tmp/yahoo.opml "Title of import folder"
```

my_yahoo_source_to_opml.sh source code:

```
if [ $# -lt 2 -o $# -gt 3 ]
then
    echo 'Usage: ./my_yahoo_source_to_opml.sh /path/to/my_yahoo_source.html /path/to/output.opml ["Title of import folder"]' >&2
    exit 1
fi

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><opml version="1.0"><body><outline title="'$3'" text="'$3'">' > "$2"

grep -o '"feedUrl":"[^"]*' $1 | sed 's|\\||g' | sed 's/$/" \/>/' | sed 's|"feedUrl":"|<outline type="rss" xmlUrl="|g' >> "$2"

echo '</outline></body></opml>' >> "$2"
```

--

**Original Dialog with My Yahoo Customer Care**

> I would like to export my My Yahoo feeds, ideally as OPML. You
>   used to have an exporter, but it is marked as deprecated. Can you please
>   return my data to me? Thanks.

--

> Thank you for writing to My Yahoo!.
>
> I understand you want to export your RSS feeds from My Yahoo! in OPML
>   format.
>
> I'm sorry, but the feature you are describing is currently not available
>   on My Yahoo!.
>
> Rest assured that I will pass along your input to the Product Team.
>
> Please don't hesitate to provide us more feedback and suggestions as we
>   would love to hear from you. The Feedback Form below goes directly to
>   our Product Team:
>
> http://feedback.help.yahoo.com/feedback.php?.src=MY&.from=cc
>
> Thank you again for contacting My Yahoo!.
>
> Regards,
>   Florence
>
> My Yahoo! Customer Care